# Nextion Display not getting updated data

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card, display, rtc

I am using an Arduino Mega to display the readings of 4 pots on a Nextion Display as well as store them on an SD Card with a time stamp. I keep getting:

`recvRetCommandFinished err`

on the serial monitor and the display does not update with time.

I have attached my code below:

```cpp
#include "Nextion.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

// Declare your Nextion objects - Example (page id = 0, component id = 1, component name = "b0") 
NexText tDate = NexText(0, 1, "tDate"); 
NexText tPot1 = NexText(0, 6, "tPot1");
NexText tPot2 = NexText(0,7, "tPot2");
NexText tPot3 = NexText(0, 8, "tPot3");
NexText tPot4 = NexText(0, 9, "tPot4");

File myFile;

void setup(void) {    
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }

  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
    //rtc.adjust(DateTime(2016, 11, 19, 19, 45, 0));   // <----------------------SET TIME AND DATE: YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS
  }

  delay(100);
    
  // You might need to change NexConfig.h file in your ITEADLIB_Arduino_Nextion folder
  // Set the baudrate which is for debug and communicate with Nextion screen
  nexInit();
 
  SPI.begin();

  int pot1 = 0;
  int pot2 = 0;
  int pot3 = 0;
  int pot4 = 0;

  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(53)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
}

void loop(void) {   
  myFile = SD.open("testpot1.csv", FILE_WRITE);
  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to testpot1.txt...");

    while(1) {
      DateTime now = rtc.now();
      myFile = SD.open("testpot1.csv ", FILE_WRITE);
      int pot1 = analogRead(A0);
      int pot2 = analogRead(A1);
      int pot3 = analogRead(A2);
      int pot4 = analogRead(A3);
      myFile.print(now.hour());
      myFile.print(":");
      myFile.print(now.minute());
      myFile.print(",");
    
      myFile.println(pot1);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot1.setText(pot1);

      myFile.println(pot2);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot2.setText(pot2);

      myFile.println(pot3);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot3.setText(pot3);

      myFile.println(pot4);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot4.setText(pot4);

      Serial.print(pot1);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pot2);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pot3);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pot4);
      Serial.print(",");
   
      delay(2000);
      myFile.close();
    }
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}
```

[image: Image of the serial Monitor]

How do I get the pot values on my display? Any help or tips would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the text components to number components on the Nextion GUI Editor. That worked as I primarily wanted to show numerical readings from the pot.

Answer (score 2):

`recvRetCommandFinished err` means something is wrong with the serial communication between the Arduino and the Nextion display; it is what [`recvRetCommandFinished()`](https://github.com/itead/Segnix/blob/master/libraries/itead_Nextion/NexHardware.cpp#L189) prints when there is an error.

Check if you are using the right pins (TX1 and RX1 for Serial1) for the serial connection to the display, the actual connections you made (RX1 to TX, TX1 to RX), the baud rate, and the cable.

Comment: Thanks. This worked and also, I changed the text components to number components on the Nextion GUI Editor.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer (if you accept the answer), so the question doesn't stay open.